# adding a foreign key in the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, foreigner

I keep getting this exception: `"SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: books.user_id: SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE ("books".user_id = 4)"`. Which sounds like there is no user_id in the books table.

So I just installed the Foreigner plugin and added `"t.integer :user_id, :null => false"` and `"add_foreign_key(:books, :users)"` in the book migration file. I ran `"rake db:migrate"`, but still it is giving me the same exception.

I am using Rails 3 in Windows and Devise to authenticate user.

HOME VIEW

```
  <p><%= link_to "Add new Book",:controller =>"book", :action => 'new' %></p>
   <% @books.each do |b| %>
  <p><%= b.author%></p>
  <p><%= b.title%></p>
  <%end%>
```

HOME CONTROLLER

```
   class HomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
  @user = current_user
  @user.books||=Book.new
  @books=@user.books
  end
  end
```

BOOK CONTROLLER

```
    class BookController < ApplicationController
  def new
 @books = Book.new
   # redirect_to :controller=>"home" ,:action=>"index"
  end

    def create
   @books = Book.new(params[:book])
   if @books.save
    render "home/index"
   #redirect_to :controller=>"home" ,:action=>"index"
   else

    render :action => 'new'
   end
  end
```

CREATE TABLE/BOOK MIGRATION

```
  class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
  create_table :books do |t|
  t.text :title
  t.text :author
  t.integer :user_id, :null => false
  t.timestamps
 end
 add_foreign_key(:books, :users)
end
```

BOOK VIEW

```
<h1>Book#new</h1>

<%= form_for(:book) do |f| %>
<p><%= f.text_field :title %></p>
 <p><%= f.text_field :author %></p>
 <p><%= f.submit "Add book"%>
```

BOOK MODEL

```
 class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 end
```

USER MODEL

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :books
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :activatable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
 attr_accessible :email, :password,             :password_confirmation,:firstname,:lastname,:school,:major,:sex,:zipcode


  end
```

ROUTE
      Campus::Application.routes.draw do
     get "book/index"

```
  get "book/edit"

   get "book/new"

   get "home/edit"

  devise_for :users
   resources :book     
  root :to=> "home#index"
  match '/book/new' =>"home#index"
   end
```

DATABASE SCHEMA

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110609055608) do

  create_table "books", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "title"
    t.text     "author"
    t.integer  "user_id",    :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "courses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "strong_ins", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "subject"
    t.string   "topic"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                               :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",   :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "password_salt",                       :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                       :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.text     "school"
    t.text     "major"
    t.string   "sex"
    t.integer  "zipcode"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

  create_table "weak_ins", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "subject"
    t.string   "topic"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user_id` column should appear in the schema after running the migration. It's not in your listing, so I'd say that's the problem. Make sure `rake db:migrate` is completing without errors. You can redo the migration with `rake db:rollback && rake db:migrate`, if necessary.

Comment: i just ran rake db:rollback and then rake db:migrate again still giving me the same exception

Comment: Can you check `log/development.log` and see if the SQL statement is being logged?

Comment: Come to think of it, `foreigner` might not work with SQLite. Try removing the `add_foreign_key` statement and running the migration again.

Comment: ok i have been able to add the foreign key but the book does not appear in Home/index view.This is the info in the dev.log file Load (3.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mBook Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE ("books".user_id = 4)[0m